# Как сделать чтоб всплывала картинка не по тригеру а по клику на нее?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Есть товар на сайте, по клику на тригер картинка всплывает, а по клику на саму картинку ничего не происходит.Как подключить всплывание по клику на картинку?

Сам тригер

```
<a href="#" class="woocommerce-product-gallery__trigger"></a>
```

В woocommerce.php подключено:

```
function new_project_woocommerce_setup() {
add_theme_support( 'woocommerce' );
add_theme_support( 'wc-product-gallery-zoom' );
add_theme_support( 'wc-product-gallery-lightbox' );
add_theme_support( 'wc-product-gallery-slider' );}
```

При том что zoom работает а lightbox нет.

Comment: Непонятно) вы написали, что при клике на "лупу" всплывает картинка. Это стандартное поведение вуккомерс

Comment: В старых версиях WC  всплывает только по клике на лупу а в новых версиях WC и по клике на саму картинку. Мне нужно чтоб по клике на картинку.